# home lab need to access servers with tablets without internet

Tags: wireless-networking

I need to access my servers from ptablets / laptops without internet ?
I have ADSL wifi, VDSL wifi routers as well as CISCO switches and Cisco routers.
I just want to access my servers or just only domain controller with my laptop / tablet without any internet ?
Im running servers on my Dell laptops so please reply me If you know any way I can just plug in my adsl or vdsl wifi router into my cisco swith or if i can just turn on wifi on my server laptop and access it straigh away ? I dont want to involve internet in this process.
Please reply me thanks.

Comment: These tablets connected to the same network as the servers?

Comment: my laptop is on the same domain as my servers. I am not worried about tablets at the moment just need to access it from my client computer and i dont wanna use a network cable or internet .

Comment: Well your question is confusing.

Comment: ok I will explain you in simple words. thing is I have a domain controller server 2012 r2 running on a dell laptop and it's connected with a cisco switch. I have a client laptop and its already joined to the domain.I just want to use that client laptop to access my domain controller without using any Lan cable , internet , teamviewer etc. Any idea How can i access it ? thanks

Comment: Your question is still not clear, you should edit the question, so your question is not confusing

Comment: Don't worry about it . Someone has already answered

Comment: You took the time to clarify your question, but you submitted a comment, instead of editing your question.  The current answer has its own problems